# Push notification for toast not working in azure

Tags: azure, windows-8

My Push notification code for toast notification is not running when run through scheduler in azure. my code is

```
     function EWSReminder() {    
          push.wns.sendToastText01("https://sin.notify.windows.com/?          token=Ysdfdhjkdjksj%2fAScjFHiwrUbS6y%2bvumj9sKUqhklsdfjgfdslcvl;dklslkskdlsdl;9XD58CMJebd04EknQY0Hgaxed6%uirutiuritubW%2fRcpdvapAYlMcnWLE360%3d", {
               text1: "Sample toast from sample insert"
            }, {
            success: function(pushResponse) {
                console.log("Sent push:", pushResponse);
            }
            );
}
```

I get this error

```
Error in script '/scheduler/EWSReminder.js'. Error: The options.client_id and options.client_secret must be specified as strings or the WNS_CLIENT_ID and WNS_CLIENT_ID environment variables must be set.
[external code]
at EWSReminder (</scheduler/EWSReminder.js>:2:16)
at </scheduler/EWSReminder.js>:1:13
[external code]
```

I can't figure out what the problem is pls help. I have applied code of all the microsoft samples available all have the same code, but none is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Client Secret and Package SID in Azure Portal (Push tab in your Mobile Service). These credentials can be obtained through Windows Store Developer Portal.

Answer (score 0):

Even I too have the same issue and I have put the values in the portal which I took from the Windows Store Developer Portal.

The below code works for me but the above code doesn't as shown by Yesh.

```
var pushWNS = require('wns');
pushWNS.sendToastText01(uri, { text1: Name }, { client_id: 'xxx', client_secret: 'xxx' },
    function (error, response)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            // success code            
        }
        else
        {
            // error handling
        }
    });
```

and also I wanted to know the difference between both the codes mentioned by me and Yesh